# Securing Passwords in a Multi-Dev nginx setup

Tags: php, mysql, security, ubuntu, nginx

We have a Ubuntu12.04+PHP+nginx setup on our servers. Our developers have access to both /usr/lib/php5/ and /var/www/ folders. We work on a lot of projects and at given time have 50-100 different apps/modules each with db active.

We would like to come up with a mechanism to secure our DB passwords with the following considerations:

- The sysadmins create the password and register it somewhere (a file, or a sqlite db or some such)
- The apps provide a key indicating which DB and what permissions level they want and this module returns an object that contains everything needed for the connection. Something like "user_manager.client1.ro", "user_manager.client1.rw".
- The mechanism should provide the specific password to the app and hence accessible by 'www-data', but all the other passwords can't be seen unless their keys are known.

We have managed to get a prototype going for this, but the central password-providing module runs in www-data space and hence the file/sqlite can always be accessed by any other file in /var/www/ or /usr/lib/php5 and hence all passwords can be compromised.

Is there a way to set things up such that the password-providing module runs at root privileges and the app request the passwords from this? I know we can build a whole new service for this, but it seems too much to build and maintain (specially because this service becomes our single point of failure.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to understand better your question: is the module written in PHP? Do you want a solution that absolutely uses this module or can you just play with file permissions? Is it mandatory that every developer maintain access to all files ?

Comment: The central password-providing module is currently in PHP and is nothing but a regular PHP class.

We are open to ideas, so anything with file permissions is fine with us.

As for developer having access to all files - considering we are a somewhat small team with each dev wearing multiple hats, separating access is going to be quite tough - so I wouldn't compromise on it.

Comment: There's no way I can think of that can solve your problem if you want each developer to access everything AND prevent them to access the database. You are giving them access to something that have that access (i.e. the code), so they WILL have access to the db. They could, for example, write a line of code that read the password and save it in a hidden file... 
I believe that there's something wrong in the question itself.

Comment: Not really. It is possible to embed the password into a connection object such that the password itself won't be visible but the connection can still be obtained - even print_r or var_dump doesn't show it then (I tested this with a prototype.) The bigger issue is that if both the module providing the credentials and the one accessing it are in the same process space, then eventually a dev can write code to get access to the raw passwords.

Comment: The intention of this exercise is not to distrust the devs, but the prevent against accidental leak due to the devs' password being compromised or something of that kind.

Answer (score 1):

Using permissions, you could do something like:

1) give one developer a user

2) chown every folder under /var/www/ to user www-data, and a specific group for that site, something like:
    /var/www/site-a   www-data   group-a
    /var/www/site-b   www-data   group-b
    etc.

3) chmod every directory (and all subdirectory and files with -R) to 770

4) add each developer to every group for which he is actually developing.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, as I mentioned in a [different answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/85761/6341), would be to 
to provide the crypto keys via an API, when an application asks for it.

Your strusted devs would then query the API with a unique key to get the relevant credentials. The key can be mapped to a set of credentials (for devs on several projects).

If you protect the API either via a [client certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake) or IP filtering you will reduce the risk of data leak (if the access key is lost, you still need to be in the right network or to have the certificate to access the API). I would favor the certificate if you trust the developers (per your comment).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to run your application that manages the credentials and hands them out to the developers from a different instance of the webserver (obviously listening on a different port) and then you can run that instance as a different user and tighten down the permissions so only that user has access to the secret files it needs.

But create an additional user, don't run it as root.

Under apache I'd point to suexec or suPHP. But since you don't use apache, that's not an option for you.